# Displaying names of those whose age is within range

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform the simple task of displaying the name, age, and occupation of those whose age is within range 35-43, and I cannot seem to get the query just right. I can get it working for the minimum age or the maximum age but never the case where I set a minimum and maximum in input. Here is my query:

```
select name, age, occupation 
from list 
where name LIKE '%$user%' 
  and (age > '$min_age' or age < '$max_age';
```

Comment: AND not OR. `age > '$min_age' AND age < '$max_age'`
Also, you're missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: Also you could use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you want people who are 35 and 43 to be included. What I would do is:

```
SELECT
    name, age, occupation
FROM list
WHERE name LIKE '%$user%'
AND (age BETWEEN '$min_age' AND '$max_age');
```

The BETWEEN operator is inclusive of the values you provide.